The stalk of a presheaf is isomorphic to the stalk of its inverse image
Let $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous map of topological spaces, and let $\mathcal O$ be a presheaf of (commutative unitary) rings over $Y$.
I'm trying to understand how the fact that colimits commute with colimits allows to prove that the stalk $\mathcal O_{f(x)}$ is isomorphic to the stalk $(f^{-1}\mathcal O)_x$.
Let us define these categories:

the category $\mathsf{O}_X$ with (1) objects the open sets of $X$ and (2) morphisms the inclusion; similarly the category $\mathsf{O}_Y$.

$i_x:\mathsf O_x\hookrightarrow \mathsf O_X$ is the full inclusion of the (subcategory of) open sets containing $x$ into the (category of) open sets of $X$.

$i_U:\mathsf O_U\hookrightarrow \mathsf O_Y$ is the full inclusion of the (subcategory of) open sets $V\subset Y$, such that $U\subset f^{-1}(V)$, into the (category of) open sets of $Y$.


In order to calculate $(f^{-1}\mathcal O)_x$, we need to calculate $\mathrm{colim}((f^{-1}\mathcal O)\circ i_x)$. What suggests to use the commutativity of colimits is that, for $U\in \mathcal O_x$, then $((f^{-1}\mathcal O)\circ i_x)(U)$ is itself a colimit, namely $\mathrm{colim}(\mathcal O\circ i_U)$. However what triggers me is that the diagrams $\mathcal O\circ i_U$ are not indexed by the same category, because $\mathsf O_U$ varies with $U$. I mean, if $\mathsf O_U$ was equal to a fixed category $\sf C$ for all $U$, then we could use the commutativity of colimits to compute a colimit indexed by $\mathsf O_x\times \mathsf C$, or also multiple colimits over $\mathsf O_x$ followed by one over $\sf C$, instead of  multiple colimits over $\sf C$ followed by one over $\mathsf O_x$. But in our case, the textbook commutativity of colimits doesn't seem to apply, because as I said $\mathsf O_U$ varies.
Do you think it is a real problem or it can be bypassed easily? Thanks for any suggestion

It's good to be careful. However, as you're clearly categorically minded, you should remember that (i) "stalk at $x$" is just preimage along ${x}\hookrightarrow X$ and (ii) adjoints compose, $f^{-1}g^{-1}=(gf)^{-1}$ as functors on presheaves (because the adjoint equation $g_\ast f_\ast=(gf)\ast$ is obvious) and in this light the desired equation becomes much more clear. You should also try to explicitly write down a map from one thing to the other; note there are always canonical homomorphisms $(f\ast\mathscr{G})_{f(x)}\to\mathscr{G}_x$.
